# Changing fonts of prompt text javafx

Tags: text, fonts, javafx, prompt

I have made a login page in javafx. Problem is I want to change the font of prompt text in the textfields. I have tried passing the argument as type label and text but it wont accept anything except String. How would I do this ( without using css, hacks etc as m still a noob) ?
I wish to change all of color, size as well as style.

How would i do this ?

Comment: Please split your questions to the different entries.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, changing the style through Java API is not possible, but it will be available in the future releases of JavaFX framework. Currently you can set the style as string, think of an embedded CSS:

```
TextField textField = new TextField("Sample");
textField.setStyle(""
        + "-fx-font-size: 30px;"
        + "-fx-font-style: italic;"
        + "-fx-font-weight: bold;"
        + "-fx-font-family: fantasy;"
        + "-fx-text-fill: blue;"
        + "-fx-background-color: aqua");
```

The meaning of the atrribute and the values it can take are explained with their limitations in "JavaFX CSS Reference" guide. Refer to it and spend some time to grab the basic styling in JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Font.font static method for changing the font of the text.

```
 Text text = new Text(50, 50, "Roboto");
 text.setFill(Color.RED);
 text.setFont(Font.font("Serif", 20)); // this will change font of your text to size 20 and family Serif
```